# How can i open an exe file using a button inElectron

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, electron, exe

I am trying to make a button open an exe file in computer but it doesn't open and it gives me this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at runExe (main.js:61)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

here is the code for my button

```
<button onclick="runExe()" id="button">click</button>
```

and i got this code form the internet and when i remove the function runExe() the exe file opens when i start the app and i want it to only open when button is clicked.

here is the code to open the exe file

```
function runExe(){
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "winRAR.exe";

child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
  if(err){
 console.error(err);
  return;
}


console.log(data.toString());
});}
```

Comment: `winRAR.exe` should be portable. Did you confirm it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The `winRAR.exe` should not be an installer. When we double click on the exe, it should open.

Comment: and how do i not make it an installer? Im trying to make something like a launcher for my games and i want the button to open that exe file. I am using winrar as an example

Comment: Download portable version of WinRAR here. 

https://www.winrarfree.net/download-file/winrar-portable/wrar_unplugged_3.9.1.1.exe

Comment: And if I want to use another example let say game.exe do I make that portable ?

Comment: game.exe is third party app or your own app?

Comment: Third party. I'm trying to make a button launch programs like games

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you cannot use `require`.

You are trying to run that code in the renderer process. If the distinction between main and renderer is new, see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes

One way to do what you want is to instead have the rendered process send the open request to the main process, where the require will work, and where opening a child process should work.

BTW, I don't know if `shell.openItem()` (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell) can be used to start any exe? If so, that might be the better way to do it.

Comment: I tried adding the code to my render.js file instead of the main.js but it gives me the same error and then I tried using shell.openItem but it tells me it cant use require. Is there a way you can help me but the code just to open the exe file? I'm trying to make a launcher for my app and the only thing I'm missing is being able to run the exe files

Comment: `require` should always be available in main process (and, actually, I thought it was always there in the renderer process). I suggest you make a minimal fully reproducible example. (Often by trying to show the problem in a dozen lines you'll discover the problem yourself!) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example